# Spring Data Neo4J Relationship with nested object

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to save a Relationship Entity which contains a nested object (so not a String, long, ...). When I save and retrieve it in my unit test, all the properties of the relationship are filled in except the nested object. I also tried adding `@fetch` to it but that does not work.
<strike>For Node Entities this is not a problem.</strike> The same problem also exists for Node Entities on further investigation.

All the examples in spring-data-neo4j-examples never contain a relationship with a nested object. Is it supported or not? If not, what would be the best solution to solve my domain model problem?

See code below:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "SEND_DOCUMENT")
public abstract class AbstractDocument implements Document {

@GraphId
private Long graphId;

@Indexed
private String documentId;

@Fetch
private StoredDocument storedDocument; //=> this one is always null

@StartNode
@Fetch
private Company fromCompany;

@EndNode
@Fetch
private Company toCompany;
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed objects both in node entities and in relationship entities, leveraging the Spring type conversion system [Spring type conversion system](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).
Provide a pair of string-to-object and object-to-string converters and declare them in the Spring configuration file.
The following is a simple scheme that I successfully used in an SDN based application. Objects extend the *Embedded* common interface to conveniently declare a single converter and are converted to/from JSON string format (this is only to get a better readability when exploring graph node properties, you can choose whatever string format you prefer).

1. String to object converter:

   ```
   final class StringToEmbeddedConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Embedded> {

       @Override
       public <T extends Embedded> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> type) {
           return new StringToEmbeddedConverter(type);
       }

       private final class StringToEmbeddedConverter<S extends String, E extends Embedded> implements Converter<S, E> {

           private Class<E> embeddedType;

           public StringToEmbeddedConverter(Class<E> embeddedType) {
               this.embeddedType = embeddedType;
           }

           @Override
           public E convert(S source) {
               if (source != null) {
                   return (E) new Gson().fromJson(source, embeddedType);
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Object to string converter:

   ```
    final class EmbeddedToStringConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<Embedded, String> {

       @Override
       public <T extends String> Converter<Embedded, T> getConverter(Class<T> type) {
           return new EmbeddedToStringConverter(type);
       }

       private final class EmbeddedToStringConverter<E extends Embedded, S extends String> implements Converter<E, S> {

           private Class<S> stringType;

           public EmbeddedToStringConverter(Class<S> stringType) {
               this.stringType = stringType;
           }

           @Override
           public S convert(E source) {
               if (source != null) {
                   return (S) new Gson().toJson(source);
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Spring configuration.

Put the following lines in the Spring configurations file to declare the converter factories:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.example.EmbeddedToStringConverterFactory"/>
            <bean class="com.example.StringToEmbeddedConverterFactory"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think SDN can persist Object fields. From the documentation:

`20.4.3 @GraphProperty: Optional annotation for property fields
... all fields that contain primitive values are persisted directly to the graph. All fields convertible to a String using the Spring conversion services will be stored as a string. Spring Data Neo4j includes a custom conversion factory that comes with converters for Enums and Dates. Transient fields are not persisted.`

I think at minimum you object field has to be serialzable, but most likely you will also have to write and register a converter which does the de/serialization. Also you dont need the @Fetch, since only relationships are lazy-loaded.